# Handling Large Batch Inserts in GridDB with Go: Transaction Timeouts and Best Practices

Tags: griddb

I've been working on a Go application that involves inserting large batches of data into GridDB. The application collects extensive sensor data, which it then batch inserts into a GridDB container at regular intervals. However, I've encountered a recurring issue where the batch insert operations are intermittently failing with transaction timeout errors, especially when the data size is quite large.

Here's an excerpt from the GridDB log indicating the transaction timeout:

```
2023-12-06T10:15:30.456-08:00 server1 12345 ERROR TRANSACTION_SERVICE [60166:DS_CON_LOCK_CONFLICT] Transaction timed out by lock conflict (elapsedMillis=502400, timeoutMillis=500000) (reason=(pId=25, rowTxnId=789, txnId=1023)) (User error, source={clientId=100, address=127.0.0.1:20001}, eventType=BATCH_INSERT(101), partition=25, statementId=2, transaction=4f2a5b9d-12e4-4c88-91c9-6d3f2a7b8d:2, containerId=10)
```

Here is a simplified version of my Go code for the batch insert operation:

```
gridstore := ConnectGridDB()
col := GetContainer(gridstore, "SensorData")
```

```
// Assume sensorData is a large slice of data to insert
for _, data := range sensorData {
err := col.Put(data)
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("Error on Put operation:", err)
break
}
}
```

```
// Committing the transaction
err := col.Commit()
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("Error on Commit operation:", err)
}
```

I've tried adjusting the batch size and experimenting with different transaction isolation levels, but the issue still persists. Could this be related to the way GridDB handles locks or transactions for batch operations?

I'm looking for insights or best practices on how to effectively manage large batch inserts in GridDB, particularly:

How to optimize batch insert operations in GridDB to avoid transaction timeouts?
Are there specific configurations in GridDB that can help manage large transactions more efficiently?
Is there a recommended approach or pattern in Go for handling such large-scale data insertions in GridDB?